# Store retrieved infos from Database in Php session

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if it was a good practice to store the infos we retrieved from a DB (more specificaly the user infos) inside a session, *useful for the login for example :*

**e.g :**

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM USER";
$result=$myConnexion->query($sql);
$line=$result->fetch_assoc();

$_SESSION['login']=$line['login'];
$_SESSION['name']=$line['name'];
...
```

It then would be easier to display infos, welcome messages and so on.
What do you think ?

*Thank you for your time*

Comment: yes its perfectly fine....!! it also reduces hassel of querying the database again and again for info you want at several places.....

Comment: yes it´s ok. I would only suggest that you use a multiple array, so you / or other can better maintain the code.

`$_SESSION['usertable'][‘login']=$line['login'];
$_SESSION['usertable'][‘name']=$line['name'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly fine. Make sure you only store Public info you might need later on, meaning don't store the password or the user's ID in the db.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine, as long as you don't store sensitive data, like the password, or the user name. You can check this for more
[Using PHP SESSION Variables to store MySQL query results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874442/using-php-session-variables-to-store-mysql-query-results)